# How to send captured traffic from guest machine (installed in Virtualbox) to host machine?

Tags: python, network-programming, wireshark, sdn, pox

I have captured traffic and stored in `capture.pcap` file.

Now I want to send/replay that traffic from guest machine (installed in VirtualBox) to the host machine. How to send captured traffic from guest machine to host machine?

Comment: Possibly the network interface in your guest, let's say "eth0", has a counterpart interface in the host. Running `tcpreplay eth0 capture.pcap` in your guest will send traffic to your host. Packets should be visible on the host's counterpart interface (I think in Virtualbox is called vboxnet0), `tcdump -i vboxnet0` should print out the packets that arrive to the host from the guest.

Comment: i have added a bridge br1 with ip 10.0.2.20 in host machine and than configure wth1 in guest machine with ip 10.0.2.10 now i have connected both machine as i am sending ICPM packets(ping) successfully from both side now tell me command to send captured packet from guest to host machine

Comment: Assuming 'eth0' is your guest's interface with 10.0.2.10 assigned, run `tcpreplay --intf1=eth0 capture.pcap` in your guest and packets should arrive in your host's br1 interface. Run `tcpdump -X i br1` in your host to check that.

Comment: Yes i got it....Thank you Diego Pino